# Better understanding matrix arithmetic?

Tags: calculus, matrices

two homework questions I answered but am unsure of..

1) Does ABA equal A²B?

2) Does ABAB equal (AB)²

My answers were:

1) False. Despite the fact that matrix arithmetic says (AB)A equals to A(BA), the order the matrices come in is important, and thus we cannot simplify the first A and the second A to A².

2) True. ABAB equals to (AB)(AB) which is just AB squared which equals (AB)².

Simple questions but just making sure I understand them properly so I can better develop my understanding of matricies.

Thanks.

Comment: Your explanations are fine. I imagine, though, this is likely for an introductory linear algebra class. It's fine to explain why something isn't true, but you should present a counterexample. Give an example where $ABA \neq A^2B$, I mean.

Comment: For 1 you should give an explicit counterexample but you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. However, for number 1, I would provide a counterexample in order to truly prove the statement.

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. Then, [$ABA=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 3 \\ 3 & 3\end{bmatrix}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=multiply+matrices&a=*C.multiply+matrices-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=%7B%7B1%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+1%7D%7D&f=MatricesOperations.theMatrix1_%7B%7B1%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+1%7D%7D&f3=%7B%7B1%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+1%7D%7D&f=MatricesOperations.theMatrix2%5Cu005f%7B%7B1%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+1%7D%7D&f4=%7B%7B1%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+1%7D%7D&f=MatricesOperations.theMatrix3_%7B%7B1%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+1%7D%7D) while [$A^2B=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 4 \\ 2 & 4\end{bmatrix}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=multiply+matrices&a=*C.multiply+matrices-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=%7B%7B1%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+1%7D%7D&f=MatricesOperations.theMatrix1%5Cu005f%7B%7B1%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+1%7D%7D&f3=%7B%7B1%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+1%7D%7D&f=MatricesOperations.theMatrix2_%7B%7B1%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B1%2C+1%7D%7D&f4=%7B%7B1%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+1%7D%7D&f=MatricesOperations.theMatrix3_%7B%7B1%2C+1%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+1%7D%7D). Thus, $ABA \neq A^2B$.

Your reasoning for number 2 already proves the statement, so it is fine.